# What type of Fiber-Connector is this?

Tags: fiber, sfp, connector

I have four of the below connections on site and need to bring them alive, yet my googling and wikipedia does not clearly show my which type of connector I have.

[image]

I assume this to be a [duplex LC connector](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/LWL-Steckverbinder#LC), yet the picture seems to show a different kind of plastic fastener?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its not LC, that is much smaller. Looks like SC.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This connector is an SC connector.

You can see pictures of it in [this Google Image seach](https://www.google.be/search?q=SC+connector&tbm=isch).